# How to test if the query is taking a longer period of time as our production database is growing ?

Tags: php, mysql, testing, database-performance, query-performance

I would like to have a test (read: whatever can send a mail) in which whenever our query is taking more than **2 seconds** to execute, it will send to me an email.
If it matters we are using cakePhp with CircleCi and PhPUnit. We have also *three databases*, first is production, second one is development and the third one is test_database.

What is the best approach to this problem ? Is there a app which can test this ?

Comment: I would go for timing the queries in the application and stashing away the results.  Then have a separate job go through the results to determine if some threshold is being missed.  I'm guessing that you don't want the query to fail if it takes over 2 seconds.

Comment: Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries.  It may be a trivial problem of having a needing a composite index.

Comment: Gordon, no off course not. We don't want to fail. How would you implement the query into an application ?

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to enable the slow query log ([read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)) on your MySQL server.

This approach will generate false positive reports: lots of one-off queries that exceed the slow query threshold will show up. But it will alert you to slowness both in the queries *you know* are possible problems and the ones *you don't know* are possible problems.  It's the latter category that's most painful.

There are ways of generating emails and elegant reports from the slow query log; your favorite search engine will find those tools. But beware emails; they are like the proverbial boy who shouted "wolf" too often.

Your best bet is to use [`mysqldumpslow`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html) once every day or two, and look for the queries for which performance is deteriorating.

A more sophisticated approach is to work out your peak-load times. For example, in many business applications 10:00 - 12:00 each weekday is a peak-load time. Then monitor for slow queries during these windows.

If you want to be **really** sophisticated, you should attempt to monitor only the slowest decile of each distinct query -- the 10% of its runs that take the longest.  Why? The average query time, or even the median query time, is deceptive. It's the outliers -- the times the query runs very slowly -- that

a. annoy your users.
b. reveal various system bottlenecks.

Dealing with indexing and tuning for your queries that have the slowest decile is a great way to keep your system in tune.

But be careful: I can almost guarantee your boss and your product manager won't understand this approach. You'll have to explain it, a lot, until they start seeing results.

Comment: With `mysqldumpslow`, use `-s t` so that you are shown the "worst" first.  Or you could use `pt-query-digest`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible for us, because we are generating around 50 Gb per day. Or this means also that I need to add some removal of the mysqldumpslow after a while ?

Comment: With that kind of volume, you're getting into DBA territory. You may want to look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually O.Jones, we have come to a solution where our only bet is sql query log. But I need to do some serious hacking. I need to enable slow query log once per week in a cron job and to see what kind of results does it send. So I believe that I am still on stackoverflow territory.